# WCF-WebHttp Send Port authenticating to Dynamics CRM fails

Tags: biztalk, dynamics-crm-online, biztalk-2013r2

I'm trying to configure a WCF-WebHttp send port for accessing the Dynamics CRM OData REST WebAPI but I hit a road block getting the authentication behavior to work.

Configuring the endpoint Url, credentials and transport security the send port fails to process messages with the error

> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Following [BizTalk 2013 to CRM 2011 Integration](http://www.dynamicscrmguide.com/biztalk-2013-to-crm-2011-integration/) I tried to use the *ClientCredential* endpoint behavior but the problem stays the same.

I am aware that the problem is to retrieve the authentication token but I have not found any way to create an endpoint behavior being able to handle this.

I have a working WCF-Custom SP targeting the SOAP endpoint but I couldn't find any trace of the schema usually provided as part of the CRM SDK in v9.0.2.4 so I figured Microsoft is gently nudging us towards the new REST Web API instead.

Comment: The issue is probably that BizTalk is trying to use TLS 1.0 to connect to the service, but the service expects TLS 1.2.  You probable need to update that end point behavior to force it to use TLS 1.2, or you need to do some registry entries that will have the entire server attempt to use TLS 1.2 in preference

Comment: The last Cumulative Update 8 promised to solve the TLS 1.2 issue and I have a working WCF-Custom SP targeting the SOAP endpoint (forcing TLS 1.2 via registry). To me it looks like nobody tried the v9.0 Web API, only the "old" OData endpoint. I've seen custom endpoint behaviors for O365 targeting Sharepoint-Online but couldn't find anything working for Dynamics CRM.

Comment: I believe that CU just makes BizTalk capable of going fully TLS 1.2 (e.g. switching off 1.0 & 1.1), you still need to do the registry changes to tell .Net to default to the secure as per the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3155464 that is linked from https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4091110/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Dynamics CRM requires TLS 1.2 as per [Microsoft Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (online) to require TLS 1.2 for connectivity](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4051700)

To enable that you either

- need to change your End Point Behaviour to tell it to use TLS 1.2 the same way that it was done for the Saleforce End Point Behaviour in this blog [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0 – How to get it working for API calls via BizTalk](https://biztalkbox.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/salesforce-disabling-tls-1-0-how-to-get-it-working-for-api-calls-via-biztalk/)
- or make sure that you have the correct CU installed as per [Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4091110/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server) and then follow the link from there to the article [MS16-065: Description of the TLS/SSL protocol information disclosure vulnerability (CVE-2016-0149): May 10, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3155464) which tells you to set the `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry key.  Note: This second option is server wide and will make ALL connections try TSL 1.2 first.

Comment: I'm definitely making progress after setting the `SchUseStrongCrypto` registry key - the resonse is still `401 Access denied` but this gives me something to work on. I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [OAuth 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/gg327838.aspx) for this? Setting it up in BizTalk is easy if you base it on [this SalesForce example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/step-3d-enabling-biztalk-server-to-send-and-receive-messages-from-salesforce#add-a-custom-wcf-behavior-for-salesforce-authentication).

Comment: This is what I already suspected but hoped to solve with an existing behavior.